# Batch change file extensions in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, automator, batch-rename

I used wget to download a website into a folder. When files have the same names, wget stores the new one as name.extension.#

Now I have hundreds of files like 1.jpg, 1.jpg.1, 1.jpg.2, etc.

How can I change every file with a .jpg* extension into plain .jpg?

EDIT: I used freeware NameChanger, which let me organize by EXIF data before changing the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/) to do this. Shareware, but: *Trial version: Name Mangler will work for 25 launches without limitation.*

You can see the original and future file  names on the left, and the configuration of *Number Sequentially* I used on the right. Important here is to manually define `.jpg` suffix, and not appending the original extension.

[image: Screenshot of suitable configuration]

---

The free [NameChanger](http://www.mrrsoftware.com/MRRSoftware/NameChanger.html) also can do this. (thanks [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)!)

[image: Screenshot of suitable configuration]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want `1.jpg.1` to be renamed to `1-1.jpg`, or you'll lose them.
Quick and dirty comes to mind: just use `sed` to construct a shell script on the fly and have `sh` run it:

```
$ ls -1 *jpg* | sed -e 's@\(.*\)\(\.jpg\.\)\(.*\)@mv \1\2\3 \1-\3.jpg@' | grep ^mv | sh
```

Strongly suggest you check the output just before the `sh` to make sure it's actually going to do the right thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'll lose

Comment: This doesn't work with filenames that have spaces or some other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

`` IFS=$'\n'; for f in `find . -name '*.jpg.*'`; do echo mv "$f" "`sed -E 's/(.*)\.jpg\.(.*)/\1-\2.jpg/' <<< "$f"`"; done ``

Another version that applies to files in all subfolders and should work with filenames that have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy to remember way of renaming multiple files in the Terminal:

```
rename 's/\.jpg.1/\.jpg/' *.jpg.1
```

Just put whatever extension after each `/\.` and make sure to specify the existing files in the second argument (`*.jpg.1` in this case)