# Automate the renaming of file in OSX

Tags: macos, filenames, batch-rename

Example: We have a folder filled with 30 images with inconsistent names. These images need to be named consistently and numerically: image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg ... image30.jpg
Can this be automated?

Comment: And which criterion would the files be named after? How do you choose the sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) monitors folders for changes and can rename newly added files.  Commercial with full-featured demo.

> Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically organizing your files according to the rules you create. It features a rule interface similar to that of Apple Mail so you should feel right at home. Have Hazel move files around based on name, date, type, what site/email address it came from (Safari and Mail only) and much more.

[image: Screenshot]

---

[Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/) is a file rename utility. Just drag & drop files on the program window and set the rules. The preview shows how the files will be named afterwards. Commercial with full-featured demo.

> The Finder is good at a lot of things, but renaming a lot of files is not one of them. Enter Name Mangler, which makes short work of all your file renaming tasks.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Your Mac comes with [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488), a tool allowing you create so-called *workflows*.

> With Automator you can automate much of what you do with your computer. Create and print a family directory with the contacts in your Address Book. Find and add images from your favorite websites to iPhoto. Print your documents to your iPad. **Instantly rename dozens of files in the Finder.**

Launch it, and select to create a new *workflow*. From the Library, add a *Get Specified Finder Items* action and a *Rename Finder Items* action (don't create copies of the files when asked about it). Drop & drop files on the first action to add them to the workflow. Configure the second as shown to *Make Sequential* with *new name* and *separated by nothing*. Run by pressing the "Play" button in the toolbar.

[image: Screenshot]

---

To do this from the command line in `bash`, enter the parent directory and run the following command:

```
declare -i C=1 ; for file in *.jpg ; do mv "$file" "image$C.jpg" ; C=C+1 ; done
```

Comment: There's also Renamer (renamer.com) and A Better Finder Rename (http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/)

Comment: c.f. [Batch change file extensions in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/421056/batch-change-file-extensions-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @slhck Thought about it, but this seems to just be about sequential naming, the other about normalizing file extensions. The Automator solution wouldn't work there. Maybe it's time for a canonical "I want to batch rename files" question?

Comment: With the full Automator treatment? Would be nice. Or make it a blog post ;)

Comment: How about the command line? Do I really need to deal with another app and ui to accomplish this?

Comment: @Fresheyeball In the future, please state *all* your requirements in your questions, not only after others have invested time to answer them.

Comment: @DanielBeck its not a requirement, its a follow up. This answer is completely acceptable, I have upvoted it and if I don't get a better answer by the end of today, I will accept it.

Comment: Hazel turned out to be really cool. Awesome answer and ver through.

Answer (score 3):

Driveby answer, in case someone lands on this page in the future: Yosemite (OSX 10.10) added batch-renaming to the finder, so now all one has to do to perform such operations as OP's is select all the files that need renaming, right/control-click on them, and select `Rename X items...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell command like this:

```
i=1;for f in *;do echo mv "$f" image$((i++)).jpg;done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks right.

Another option is to run `brew install rename` and then run `rename -n '$_=$N.".jpg"' *`. Remove `-n` if the output looks right. `$N` is the file number starting from 1, `$_` is the current line, and `.` is used for string concatenation in Perl.

More examples:

```
i=1;for f in *;do mv "$f" $(printf %03d $i).jpg;let i++;done
i=1;for f in *;do mv "$f" $(printf %03d $i).${f##*.};let i++;done
IFS=$'\n';i=1;for f in $(ls -rt);do mv "$f" "$((i++)) $f";done
for f in *.mp3;do mv "$f" "$(printf %02d ${f%% *}) ${f#* }";done
for f in *;do b=${f%.*};x=${f#*.};mv $f ${b%-*}-$(printf %03d ${b#*-}).$x;done
shopt -s extglob;for f in !(*.*);do mv $f $f.txt;done
for f in *;do mv "$f" "${f//[^a-zA-Z0-9.]}";done
rename 's/.*ep(..).*/Example EP$1 720p HDTV x264.srt/' *.srt
```

`${f##*.}` removes the longest `*.` pattern from the start and `${f%.*}` removes the shortest `.*` pattern from the end. `${f//[^a-zA-Z0-9.]}` removes all characters except `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`.

Comment: You could also use something like ruby -e 'Dir["*.png"].each_with_index { |f, i| File.rename(f, "prefix #{i}.png") }'

Worked perfect!